# How can i fix this bash problem?

Tags: bash, xinput

I am trying to set xinput to run at startup to switch some mouse button functions. The problem though is it is not working obviously.

I want to go from this:

```
xinput set-button-map 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

or

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

to this:

```
xinput set-button-map 8 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

or

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I wrote this in a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
$xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

If I run that xinput command directly it works great even if I use the ID instead of name. If I run the file though then it tells me "set-button-map: command not found".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

instead of

```
$xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

With `$xinput`  you try to use an environment variable `xinput` which doesn't exists and thus just gets ignored. So Bash actually tries to run

```
set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

As the command `set-button-map` doesn't exists you get an error.